# Merge when not matched by source without deleting other rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to update a target table from a source table using merge.  The source table does not have all the rows that the target table does, so when I do `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE`, all the target rows not in my source table get deleted. I only want to delete specific ones.

So for example I have this in my source table:

| Userid | skill_id | default_skill |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1132 | 2160 | 1 |

My target table has many rows, but here is an example:

| Userid | skill_id | default_skill |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1132 | 421 | 0 |
| 1132 | 2160 | 1 |
| 1131 | 789 | 1 |

If I simple do `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN Delete`, it will delete 1131 userid from the target table because it is not in the source.  I only want to delete the one from the target table that doesn't match the source.  So it would delete the |1132|421|0| row.

Would I merge on the userid then when matched and the skill_ids don't match, delete?  But what if I need a when matched but they do match and I just want to update the `default_skill` column. I can't have multiple WHEN MATCH can I?

This is my current merge that I am trying to do it in:

```
    MERGE appuser_skills USING 
    (
        SELECT
             userid,
             #tmp.username,
             s.value AS skill_id,
             CASE
                WHEN s.value = #tmp.primaryskillid THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END AS default_skill
        FROM
            #tmp
            CROSS APPLY
            dbo.splitinteger(#tmp.skilllist,',') s
            JOIN skill WITH(NOLOCK) ON skill.skill_id = s.value
    ) a
    ON appuser_skills.user_id = a.userid AND appuser_skills.skill_id = a.skill_id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
        default_skill = CASE
                            WHEN a.default_skill = 1 THEN 1
                            ELSE 0
                        END
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT
        (
            user_id,
            skill_id,
            weight,
            proficiency,
            default_skill
        )
    VALUES
        (
            (SELECT user_id FROM appuser WHERE appuser.username = a.username),
            a.skill_id,
            0,
            0,
            a.default_skill
        );
```

Comment: I took some time going through your code, and it seems correct, joining on both userid and skillid and updating the default skill accordingly. Does it produce unwanted results? can you post such?

Comment: What you do is change so your merge looks like: ; with cte as (select * from target t where exists(select 1 from sources s where s.Userid = t.Userid)) merge cte as target using source s ON s.id = target.id ... This way, you will only work with relevant rows in target table

Comment: If you read MS docs on the Merge statement, you will find that it allows you to specify additional conditions for each match: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#and-clause_search_condition . It even gives you example further down: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#and-clause_search_condition

Comment: Updated: You are looking for something along the lines of `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND appuser_skills.userid = a.userid  THEN DELETE` . This way you will only delete when user IDs match.

Comment: @Alex, you cant do that, i get The identifier 'a.userid' cannot be bound. Only target columns and columns in the clause scope are allowed in the 'WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE' clause of a MERGE statement.

Comment: @siggemannen can you put the cte as an answer so i can see your code.  Can you take my code and change it for what you are saying?  Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed you also want an insert. I don't think all those can be solved by merge. I think it's time to do what you should've done from the beginning, don't use merge, or at least use several statements:

```sql
-- Create test data
drop table #source
drop table #target
SELECt  *
into #source
FROM    (
    VALUES  (1132, 2160, 1)
    ,   (1132, 666, 0)
) t (Userid,skill_id,default_skill)

select *
into #target
FROM    (
    VALUES  (1132, 421, 0)
    ,   (1132, 2160, 0)
    ,   (1131, 789, 1)
    ) t (Userid,skill_id,default_skill)


-- The actual merge
;WITH target AS (
    select *
    from #target t -- We work only with users in the source table
    WHERE   EXISTS(
            SELECT  1
            FROM    #source s
            WHERE   s.Userid = t.UserId
    )
)
merge target AS t
USING #source s
    ON  s.UserID = t.UserID
    AND s.skill_id = t.skill_id
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT (UserId, skill_id, default_skill)
VALUES (s.UserId, s.skill_id, s.default_skill)
WHEN MATCHED and s.default_skill <> t.default_skill THEN UPDATE
    SET default_skill = s.default_skill
output inserted.*, deleted.*, $action
;
-- Separate insert of completely new users
insert into #target (
    Userid, skill_id, default_skill
)
select  Userid, skill_id, default_skill
FROm    #source s
WHERE   NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT  1
        FROM    #target t
        WHERE   t.Userid = s.userId
        --AND   t.skill_id = s.skill_id -- Shouldn't be needed
    )

select *
from #source
select *
from #target
```

I choose to split out the INSERT of completely new users, since it's usually the easiest to check using WHERE NOT EXISTS.

For the delete, i make sure target rows participating in the merge only comes from users in the #source-table.

Comment: what would you do if not merge? just insert, update and delete statements?  The original script, which i didnt write used a cursor and that was horrible and slow.  It is just a very complicated script.  this is only a small fraction of it.  Not to mention the database design is HORRIBLE (Not mine, fyi, lol.  Thank you much for the help

Comment: yeah, the old-fashioned insert/update/delete gives you more flexibility and it's simpler to write / debug. Merge has a lot of quirks and actually some bugs which at least to me makes it avoid it, unless i'm doing the most simple upserts

Comment: Yeah, sometimes one gotta work with bad code, been there, got the shirt :D

Comment: I need that shirt, lol.  Maybe ill try the IUD for this particular case.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

- The `WHEN MATCHED AND target.default_skill <> source.default_skill THEN` condition will check if the `default_skill` values do not match between the source and target tables for matched rows. In that case, it performs an update to set the `default_skill` value in the target table to match the source table.
- The `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE` condition remains the same : it will delete rows from the target table that do not have a match in the source table.

```sql
MERGE appuser_skills AS target
USING 
(
    SELECT
        userid,
        s.value AS skill_id,
        CASE
            WHEN s.value = #tmp.primaryskillid THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS default_skill
    FROM
        #tmp
        CROSS APPLY dbo.splitinteger(#tmp.skilllist,',') s
        JOIN skill WITH(NOLOCK) ON skill.skill_id = s.value
) AS source
ON (target.user_id = source.userid AND target.skill_id = source.skill_id)
WHEN MATCHED AND target.default_skill <> source.default_skill THEN
    UPDATE SET target.default_skill = source.default_skill
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
    DELETE;
```